# What "costs" more, memory space or recursive calls?

Tags: memory-management

Assume we want to implement a data structure, say a binary search tree.

One can implement every method of the tree without using recursion at all, by allocating each node additional space for a pointer to its parent in the tree. In that way, we can traverse the tree however we wish.
The advantage is clear - we do not need to make recursive calls in order to process parents informantion, too much recursive calls may lead to a stack overflow.
On the other hand, using that parent's pointer requires O(n) memory space, which may be serious when dealing with a lot of data.

So my question is - what considered to be more efficient, implementing the tree using recursive calls, or maybe implementing the tree using parent's pointers (the latter may be even more convenient to implement and lead to more readable code) ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: These aren't the only two options though, you can also use an explicit stack instead of recursion.

Comment: The "cost" of an extra address-value is `O(1)` per item, or `O(n)` overall (for `n` items), that's almost the opposite of "serious". (The _real_ problem is the risk of corrupting your structure because you need to keep 2 references in-sync all the time). Also, you don't necessarily need to store pointers to jump around a tree: if you use the heap structure to represent a tree then you need _zero_ extra space because every node is directly addressable given the base address and a simple `log2` calculation.

Comment: And generally an additional n pointers is not that big of a deal. If you are on a very memory constraint system it may be but we would need more details.0

Comment: @Dai And what about binary search tree? you would have to hold pointers for the parents

Comment: @harold The risks are not the same as for recursion?

Comment: @luk2302 So holding pointers to the parents is a better option?

Comment: @DirichletIsaPartyPooper You will find answers to all your questions inside your copy of the CLRS book. (As for BSTs: yes, there are overheads involved, but you wouldn't use a BST in the first place unless you had a good reason to use it _and_ you were aware of how to mitigate those issues, perhaps by _not_ using a BST in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

There is no possible way for an explicitly recursive function to beat the equivalent stack-based implementation in terms of memory consumption. Any recursive function can be mechanically transformed into a non-recursive function with the same behavior, and its stack will not need to store frame pointers or return addresses. The advantage of the recursive implementation is solely code clarity.

Comment: What about tail-call optimization?

Comment: @Dai I dunno, what *about* tail call optimization?

Comment: That's on me: I didn't think things through. Heh.